# div.innerHTML+=img tag is not allowing object-fit:fill styling

Tags: javascript, css

UPDATE - After deleting this post to investigate along a different line of reasoning, I still end up with this *very same question*.  Note very minor changes now, as I am using `document.querySelector('div[id=\'animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2\']').` to avoid any ambiguity about the `div` id.  I have also switched to using exclusively the style.width and style.height instead of simple width and height.  I've applied those changes to this post content.
Original OP below:

Something about adding `img` elements into a `div` with div`.innerHTML+=img` prevents `object-fit: fill;` (the style directive that dynamically sizes `img` to fill its container) from having any effect for me.  Instead of trouble-free size-tracking (if you will) supposed to be enforced by `object-fit: fill;`, I'm having to iterate over all the many `img` elements to resize them during `div` resizing.  **This even though the `img` elements do become `childNodes` of the containing `div`!**

Frankly, I'm confessing that I don't know the javascript instruction to use that will insure a newly created `img` element actually gets placed 'into'(?) the intended `div` DOM container so as to cause `img` rendered size to track the size of its containing `div` during `div` resizing.  If div`.innerHTML+=img` doesn't 'containerize' (if you will) the `img` tags, what does?

Obviously I am unsure of correct terminologies, which hinders me in researching this concept.  Forgive me for that, and enlighten me, please.

The `div` will get resized by height and width slider range elements, the height slider code being:

```
<input type="range" min="-2800" max="-50" step="1" list="tickmarks" value="-258" id="snapsslidervert"
oninput="
 document.querySelector('div[id=\'animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2\']').style.width=parseInt(parseInt(this.value)+440)+'px'
"
orient="vertical"
>
```

where `animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2` has had `img` elements attached via

```
document.querySelector('div[id=\'animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2\']').innerHTML += '<img src=\"'+table_el.rows[rowindex].cells[1].children[0].href+'\" style=\'position:absolute;top:15px;height:'+parseInt(snapsdirectory.offsetHeight)+'px;width:'+mainjpgviewer2.width+';z-index:1;object-fit: fill;\' />';
```

You'll see the `object-fit: fill;` directive at the very end of the `img` above

UPDATE - To prove that the `div` is not null, the following iteration loop performs in the same function as, and a line or tow after the div`.innerHTML+=img` instruction without console error as it acts on the `img` elements' zIndex properties:

```
  for(var i=0;i<document.querySelector('div[id=\'animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2\']').childNodes.length;i++)
  {
     document.querySelector('div[id=\'animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2\']').childNodes[i].style.zIndex='0'
  }
```

SNIPPET:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Add another img tag into div" onclick="addimg()" style="position:absolute;left:0px" />
<input type="range" min="-2800" max="-50" step="1" value="-200" id="snapsslidervert" style="position:absolute;left:220px"
oninput="
 document.querySelector('div[id=\'animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2\']').style.height=parseInt(0-parseInt(this.value))+'px'
"
orient="vertical"
>
<div style="border:1px solid red;width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;top:40px;z-index=-1" id="animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2"></div>
<script>
function addimg()
{document.querySelector('div[id=\'animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2\']').innerHTML += '<img src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Heliconius_charithonia_2021.jpg/1200px-Heliconius_charithonia_2021.jpg\" style=\'position:absolute;top:15px;height:'+animatordivalertsdirectorytomainjpgviewer2.style.height+';z-index:1;object-fit: fill;\' />';}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having a bit of difficulty following exactly what the problem is. Could you put a working snippet into your answer which demonstrates the problem. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I had to use % for the height and width, not px.  Thank you to everyone, especially, A Haworth, for not losing your tempers over this!

Answer (score 0):

The `object-fit: fill;` css directive does not work when both childNode dimensions are set to hard units like pixels.  It can only be applicable when at least one childNode dimension is specified in %, and also when that is the dimension expected to track the container change.  The other dimension may be left unspecified, in which case it will assume a default of "auto", or it may be a specific hard unit amount, or a %.  In my case, I have now set both dimensions of the childNode to "100%" for maximum visibility.  These settings allow the directive to work as expected, responsively adjusting to `div` container dimension changes.